# Which scripture contains the event of Shiva beheading Vinayaka?

Tags: shiva, ganesha, parvati, reference-request

Consider the sequence of events : Parvati making Vinayaka, Vinayaka disallowing Shiva, Shiva beheading Vinayaka, Shiva joining Elephant's head on Vinayaka's body, etc.,

Which scripture contains this sequence of events?

Comment: Different set of events mentioned in Puranas about Ganesh having elephant head relating to different mahakalpas perhaps.  Because Ganesh elephant head also has yogic tattva...

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti can you provide some alternate to Shiva mahapurana as mentioned in the answer? Also what is the yogic tattva you are talking about? Thank you

Comment: @PrakashK not expert in Puranas but Yogic meaning of Ganesha is Sushumna Nadi. Sushumna Nadi has trunk shape ! Each deities have their own yogic meaning and that will be eternal. Different events take place to have that meaning. There's story of Shani dev seeing Ganesha and Ganesha losing his head too in Puranas. Another story is there related to Vishnu.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti Thank you. That's interesting, will find out more about it. It would help if you can point me to something that tells more about the yogic meanings. Thanks again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These events are mentioned in Shiva Mahapurana in the sequence given in question.

1. First Devi Parvati creating Ganesha (Vinayaka) from dirt of her body is mentioned in [Section 2.4 - Rudra-saṃhitā (4): Kumāra-khaṇḍa: Chapter 13](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226133.html).

   > 20. Thinking thus the goddess created a person with all the characteristics, out of the dirt from her body.
   > 21. He was spotless and handsome in every part of his body. He was huge in size and had all brilliance, strength and valour.
2. After that Devi Parvati told Ganesha that no one should enter in her place without her permission and gave him a stick. After some time Lord Shiva came there and he was disallowed by Ganesha. It is mentioned in same chapter.

   > 30. Thus placing her son at the doorway, Pārvatī began to take bath with her friends, unworried.
   > 31. O excellent sage, at this very moment Śiva who is eagerly indulgent and an expert in various divine sports came near the door.
   > 32. Not knowing that he was lord Śiva, the consort of Pārvatī, Gaṇeśa said—“O sir, without my mother’s permission you shall not go in now.
   > 33. My mother has entered the bath. Where are you going now? Go away” saying thus, he took up his staff to ward him off.
3. After that the great fight between Shiva ganas and Ganesha started. Lord Ganesha defeated every one. After a great battle Lord Shiva beheaded Lord Ganesha. It is mentioned in [Chapter 16](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226136.html).

   > 34. Securing this opportunity, the Trident-bearing deity came there and cut off his head with his trident.
   > 35. O Nārada, when the head of Gaṇeśa was cut off, the armies of the gods and the Gaṇas stood still.
4. After that Devi Parvati infuriated and to please her Lord Shiva joined the head of an elephant to Ganesha's body. It is mentioned in [Chapter 17](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226137.html).

   > 49. They paid homage to it and started towards the north. It was a single-tusked elephant that they met.
   >
   > 50-51. They took the head and fitted it to the body. After joining it, the gods bowed to Śiva, Viṣṇu and Brahmā and spoke—“What has been ordered by you has been carried out by us. Let the task left incomplete be performed now.”
   >
   > 52. Then the Pārṣadas shone happily. After hearing those words they awaited eagerly what Śiva would say.
   > 53. Then Brahmā, Viṣṇu and other gods spoke after bowing to lord Śiva who is free from the ill effects of the attributes.
   > 54. They said:—“Since we all are born out of your brilliant Energy let that Energy come into it by the recitation of the Vedic mantras.
   > 55. Saying so, they jointly sprinkled the holy water, invoked by the mantras on that body after remembering Śiva.
   > 56. Immediately after the contact of the holy water the boy was resuscitated to life and joined with consciousness. As Śiva willed, the boy woke up as from a sleep.